# Whirlpool top load washer noisy during agitation

Tags: washing-machine

I have a whirlpool top load washer that makes a noise similar to a fast sawing sound. It still agitates fine and all other functions are normal. Its' just noisy during agitation. I have just replaced the entire agitation tower and related parts but still get the sound.

Comment: I’m having the same issue with mine. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 2):

It was a washer I bought from a rental center. it was missing three springs I found out which caused the bearings and the transmission to go out. In the end we ended up getting a new washer. It was cheaper than repairing the old one.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and giving your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be several things. Normally I don't post links but it could be SO many things.

I've used this youtube contributor many times. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhbfCp8yb0c) may help and is specific to a loud top load whirlpool.

If not, here is another [link](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/184652/Why+is+my+Whirlpool+top-loading+washer+making+a+very+bad+noise) with many potential solutions for loud whirlpool washers. Below are some of the potential fixes:

**Tub Bearing**

If the washer is making a loud noise the tub bearing might need to be replace. This is a very involved repair and will require disassembling most of the washer. The manufacturer recommends that if possible the complete outer tub and bearing be replaced rather than attempting to replace just the bearing in the tub. If the bearing is bad the problem is going to get worse very quickly and so either the drum and bearing will need to be replaced or the washing machine.

**Tub Seal and Bearing Kit**

If the washer is making loud noise the tub seal and bearing kit might need to be replace. This is a very involved repair and will require disassembling most of the washer. If the bearing is bad the problem is going to get worse very quickly and so either the tub seal and bearing kit will need to be replaced or the washing machine.

**Rear Drum with Bearing**

If the washer is making a loud noise the rear drum with bearing might need to be replace. On this washer the bearing might not be sold separately, the entire rear drum might have to be replaced. This is a very involved repair and will require disassembling most of the washer. However, the problem is going to get worse very quickly and so either the drum and bearing will need to be replaced or the washing machine.

**Bearing**

If the washer is making a loud noise the tub bearing might need to be replace. This is a very involved repair and will require disassembling most of the washer. The manufacturer recommends that if possible the complete outer tub and bearing be replaced rather than attempting to replace just the bearing in the tub. If the bearing is bad the problem is going to get worse very quickly and so either the drum and bearing will need to be replaced or the washing machine.

**Drive Pulley**

If the washer is making a loud noise the drive pulley might be worn out, cracked, loose or bent. Remove the drive pulley and inspect it carefully. If it is damaged or defective replace it.

**Pulley**

If the washer is making a loud noise the drive pulley may be worn out. If the drive pulley is loose or wobbling it will need to be replaced

**U-Joint Kit**

If the washer is making a loud noise the U-Joint may have failed. This is the primary drive mechanism for the agitation motion in this washer. Although this is not a very difficult repair for a DIY'er with some experience, the part is expensive and so it may be worth considering a new washer.

**Motor Coupling**

If the washer is making a loud noise the motor coupling might have failed. The motor coupling connects the motor to the washer transmission. It is designed to fail if the washer is overloaded in order to protect both the motor and transmission.

**Clutch**

If the washer is making a loud noise in the spin cycle, the clutch assembly might be worn out. The clutch assembly makes the connection between the transmission and the inner tub. It is designed to allow the tub to get up to the proper spin speed gradually. As the clutch wears out it may become loud during spin or just after the spin cycle finishes. The clutch is not repairable, if it is loud or not working properly it will need to be replaced.

**Transmission**

If the washer is making a loud noise the transmission might be worn out or defective. There are many other more likely causes for noise from a washer. If the noise turns out to be caused by the transmission it may have to be replaced.

**Drain Pump**

If the washer is making a loud noise the drain pump might be going bad or might have something caught in it. Remove the drain pump from the washer and inspect it carefully. Look for anything that might be caught in it, a piece of wire, plastic, etc. If nothing is wrong with the pump, but it's still noisy it will have to be replaced.

**Drive Motor**

If the washer is making a loud noise the drive motor bearings may have worn out. Washer motors are normally almost silent when they run. If the motor is run without a belt hooked up to it and it's loud it will have to be replaced.